# What is a Erc20 (UBT) token I received in my wallet according to EtherScan?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, etherscan, airdrop

I look in my EtherScan and it says that 5 days ago and 10 in value I received a token called Erc20(UBT) and I click on it, it's a Universal Bonus Token that came from an address = 0x00000000000... When I click on my token balances there's the 10 UBT and above it is the ERC20 contract address.

What is this?

Comment: It's some airdropped, free tokens that someone has kindly sent to 100,000 addresses. A way to distribute and bootstrap a new token, rather than doing a presale. Do with it what you will :-)

Answer (score 1):

Some people create their own tokens and send some of these tokens to random people in order to attract attention. These tokens are usually worthless since [giving coins away to strangers is a very poor way to create value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auroracoin).